# Does somebody know what this piece of equipment is?

Tags: tools, ships

[image: equipment]

I got this equipment from a sailor, I have no idea what this is. Does anyone know?

Comment: Safety harness?

Comment: Could be a harness;  could be a  boom/yardarm range-of-motion limiter.  Heck, could be something from his collection of bedroom   toys.

Comment: Probably. Interesting.